# Is there any way to pass shell variable in awk pattern command like below?

Tags: shell, awk

Here's generic command I want to pass variable at DEFINE keyword place but failing

```
awk '/DEFINE/,/REPLACE/' file
```

Here's what I have tried

```
line=DEFINE
awk -v myvar=$line '/myvar/,/REPLACE/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
line=DEFINE
awk -v myvar="$line" '($0~myvar),/REPLACE/{print}'
```

Example:

```
$ seq 1 10 | awk -v x=5 '($0~x),/8/'
5
6
7
8
```

See [Passing variables to range patterns in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199782/passing-variables-to-range-patterns-in-awk) for more details